# Querying Global Address List with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to query the Global Address List using Microsoft Graph.  I've worked with and adapted the sample code from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-snippets-sample.git -- however, I'm still having trouble.  I've seen this article -- [Global Address List Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912160/global-address-list-graph-api) -- which indicates I need to use the "/contacts" endpoint.  However, I don't see how this helps me when I'm using the Microsoft.Graph library.  Is there some method or collection within the Microsoft.Graph library that will allow me to read the GAL?

Answer (score 1):

"GAL" is a MAPI concept that doesn't really apply to Graph. With Graph, you just read the users or contacts in your company's Active Directory. By combining both lists, you come close to what you'd see in the GAL in a MAPI client.

To do that, you would list users as doc'ed here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list

Using the library, I believe this will get you started:

```
client.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

For contacts, it's a lot trickier with the Graph library. Organizational contacts are only supported in the beta version of Microsoft Graph, which the client library doesn't support unfortunately. (See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/108) for info). Michael Mainer did a [write up of how you can generate your own beta version of the library](https://github.com/MIchaelMainer/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-beta) if you're interested.

The info on querying organizational contacts is found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/orgcontact.

Comment: I'm already doing what you suggest.  However, I think there's a difference between USERS (who are members of my organization and have logon permissions) and CONTACTS (who can include people outside my organization).  This article -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912160/global-address-list-graph-api -- seems to indicate that I CAN get to the GAL from Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Well no, it indicates you can get organization contacts, which are a subset of the GAL. :) To replicate the GAL, you would need to merge both the info from the /users endpoint and the /contacts endpoint. And yes, I know I'm being nitpicky -_-. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2021, doesn't appear to be an easy "Export Global Address List" API from Microsoft. There appear to be manual methods (e.g. using the Exchange Admin interface) but nothing programmatic.

Below is broad strokes exercise for creating an approximation (that may be sufficient for your needs). A more accurate exercise may be to export the GAL from a official client (e.g. Outlook/Outlook Web/Exchange Admin interface). Its possible that in some cases the GAL is user specific which may make GAL export concept significantly more involved.

### GAL export exercise:

---

### APIs:

- MS Graph API (available via HTTP, e.g. GET/POST)

  - [Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)
  - [Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)
  - Some of the above only allowed certain properties accessible by individual record query - I needed to get the whole list then iterate through each record one by one to get all needed properties.
- Exchange Powershell (available via Powershell)

  - [Get Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) (for flags not exposed by Graph/Users)
  - [Get-DistributionGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps) (for flags not exposed by Graph/Groups)

Azure Functions can be used to run these queries serverless/"API-ified". Azure App Registration can be used as OAuth app that can be granted the permissions to access the above. [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) is handy for testing Graph requests.

### Put it together:

Smash the datasets together and then filter out on fields. Some flags are:

- `hideFromAddressLists`
- `hideFromOutlookClients`
- `HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled`
- `showInAddressList`,
- some conditions you have to manually check for, e.g.

  - if no provisioned plans (i.e. unlicensed)
  - if no email address
  - etc.