# Get Global Address List from Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create an address book which contains all contacts of my organization. 
I tried the request: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contact` how its described in the Microsoft documentation. But it does not show me the contacts of the Global Address List(organization), just my personal.

Comment: This may sound silly but are you sure your using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts and not https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts ? as the results sounds like the latter.

Comment: Yeah, i am sure. Maybe i really have the not set the right permissions. Do you know what permissions are needed? I set the all contact permissions and orgContact. Did i forget one?

Comment: Have you look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748254/querying-global-address-list-with-microsoft-graph?

Comment: OrgContact.Read.All is all you should need. The weird thing is it should return Access Denied if it is permission related. What do the results look like eg the Id format would be different for directory contacts vs Mailbox contacts

Comment: It works but it only gets the business contacts. In my case i want to retrieve all users(employees) of my organization. Sorry for misunderstandings in my description. I researched, that i have to enable the Directory.Read.All permission to be able to return a list of all users.